# managing sessions on login nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2, ejs

I am trying to manage user sessions in nodejs. I have built a dashboard where people will be able to manage their products for inventory and such. I basically have it running right now where a user logs in, and it stores there username in a global variable, and then userAuth gets set to true. Obviously in a prod env this would not work, so I am trying to manage each session. the user should log on, and they should have their own session, and all their database creds should be pulled from my master table, and then used for that specific session. multiple users should be able to use this and edit their products and inventory at the same time. I have tried express-session, but no luck, I'm doing something wrong but not sure where to start really. here's my login code:

```
//LOGIN FUNCTIONALITY
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {

  //defining variables for users username & password inputs
  const inputUsername = req.body.inputUsername;
  const inputPassword = req.body.inputPassword;

  //functionality to query db by username
  var userLogin = "select * from login where USERNAME = ?";
  ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnMaster, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(userLogin, [inputUsername], function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

  //if the query returns results that are > 0
  if (rows.length > 0) {
    var pass = "";
    userSessionId = req.body.sessionID
    var sessUsername = userUsername

    //loop for getting those values that correspond with the username of the user
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      userUsername = rows[i]["USERNAME"];
      pass = rows[i]["PASSWORD"];
      firstName = rows[i]["FN"];
      lastName = rows[i]["LN"];
      company = rows[i]["COMPANY"];
      ibmdbconnDash = rows[i]["DBCONNSTRINGDASH"];
      ibmdbconnBlog = rows[i]["DBCONNSTRINGBLOG"];
      mailerStatus = rows[i]["MAILERSTATUS"];

      //these will be more secure when time comes
      cloudinaryName = rows[i]["CLOUDINARYNAME"];
      cloudinaryKey = rows[i]["CLOUDINARYKEY"];
      cloudinarySecret = rows[i]["CLOUDINARYSECRET"];
    }

    //comparing user input password to hashed db password
    bcrypt.compare(inputPassword, pass, function (err, result) {
      console.log("result is " + result);
      //if the result of the compare is true, then redirect to the index function
      if (result == true) {
        console.log("login works");
        userAuth = "true"
        res.redirect("/index");
      } else {
        //if compare returns false, re-render login page
        userAuth = "false";
        res.render("login.ejs");
        alert("Incorrect username or password. Please try again");
      }
    });
    //if the entire query returns rows < 1 (username and password don't match, then re-render login page)
  } else {
    userAuth = "false";
    res.render("login.ejs");
    alert("Incorrect username or password. Please try again");
  }

  conn.close(function () {
    console.log("closed the function /login");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

global variables

```
 var userAuth = ""
    var userName = "";
    var firstName = "";
    var lastName = "";
    var company = "";
    var password = "";
    var ibmdbconnMaster =
      "db2 conn string";
    var ibmdbconnDash = "";
    var ibmdbconnBlog = "";
    var userUsername = "";
    var mailerStatus = "";
    var cloudinaryName = "";
    var cloudinaryKey = "";
    var cloudinarySecret = "";
```

I have tried implementing sessions using express-sessions, the code I had set up for that was the standard code from their site:

```
app.use(session({
secret: "sec",
resave: false,
uninitialized: true,
}))
```

main index / landing page (dashboard) function

```
   //DEFINING GLOBAL VARIABLES FOR AUTH
var sessionID = "";
var numOfOrders = "";
var numOfUsersM = "";
var userAuth = ""
var userName = "";
var firstName = "";
var lastName = "";
var company = "";
var password = "";
var ibmdbconnMaster =
  "db conn string";
var ibmdbconnDash = "";
var ibmdbconnBlog = "";
var userUsername = "";
var mailerStatus = "";
var cloudinaryName = "";
var cloudinaryKey = "";
var cloudinarySecret = "";

//manage sessions
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret-key',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}))

//rendering login page
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login.ejs");
});

/
//LOGIN FUNCTIONALITY
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
//     console.log("sessionsid is: " + req.body.sessionID)
//  sessionID = req.body.sessionID
  //defining variables for users username & password inputs
  const inputUsername = req.body.inputUsername;
  const inputPassword = req.body.inputPassword;

  //functionality to query db by username
  var userLogin = "select * from login where USERNAME = ?";
  ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnMaster, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(userLogin, [inputUsername], function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      //if the query returns results that are > 0
      if (rows.length > 0) {
        var pass = "";
        //var userUsername = ""
        userSessionId = req.body.sessionID
        var sessUsername = userUsername
        //loop for getting those values that correspond with the username of the user
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          var userUsername1 = rows[i]["USERNAME"];
          pass = rows[i]["PASSWORD"];
          firstName = rows[i]["FN"];
          lastName = rows[i]["LN"];
          company = rows[i]["COMPANY"];
          ibmdbconnDash = rows[i]["DBCONNSTRINGDASH"];
          ibmdbconnBlog = rows[i]["DBCONNSTRINGBLOG"];
          mailerStatus = rows[i]["MAILERSTATUS"];
          cloudinaryName = rows[i]["CLOUDINARYNAME"];
          cloudinaryKey = rows[i]["CLOUDINARYKEY"];
          cloudinarySecret = rows[i]["CLOUDINARYSECRET"];
        }

        //comparing user input password to hashed db password
        bcrypt.compare(inputPassword, pass, function (err, result) {
          console.log("result is " + result);
          //if the result of the compare is true, then redirect to the index function
          if (result == true) {
            console.log("login works");
            var userAuth1 = "true"
            //successful login
            req.session.user = {
                userUsername1,
                userAuth1
            }
            console.log("rquu1 " + req.session.user.userUsername1)
             res.redirect("/index");
          } else {
            //if compare returns false, re-render login page
            userAuth1 = "false";
            res.render("login.ejs");
            alert("Incorrect username or password. Please try again");
          }
        });
        //if the entire query returns rows < 1 (username and password don't match, then re-render login page)
      } else {
        userAuth = "false";
        res.render("login.ejs");
        alert("Incorrect username or password. Please try again");
      }

      conn.close(function () {
        console.log("closed the function /login");
      });
    });
  });
});



//function for logout page
app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  userAuth = "false";
  res.render("login.ejs");
});


//RENDERING INDEX PAGE WITH INFORMATION ABOUT PRODUCTS AND ANALYTICS
app.get("/index", (req, res) => {
//   if (userAuth == "true") {
    if (req.session.user) {
        console.log(req.session.user)
    console.log("username is: " + userName);
   
    
   

    pageName = "/index";

    numOfOrdersFun(req, res, numOfOrders)
    //end of location manager

    //initializing counter
    var counterTest2 = "select * from VISITORS";
    ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      conn.query(counterTest2, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          var dbCountCurrent = rows[i]["NUM"];
        }

        console.log("currentCount " + dbCountCurrent);

        conn.close(function () {
          console.log("closed the function /login");
        });

        //showing information for products
        var showingDBINFO = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS";
        ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          conn.query(showingDBINFO, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            
            //rendering page with all users information, products, and data from login. also a redirect from the login info.
            res.render("index", {
              page_title: "index",
              data: rows,
              userName: userName,
              FN: firstName,
              LN: lastName,
              CO: company,
              dbcc: dbCountCurrent,
              numOfOrders: numOfOrders,
              mailerStatus: mailerStatus,
            });

            conn.close(function () {
              console.log("closed the function /index);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
      req.session.user.userAuth1 == "false"
    res.render("login.ejs");
  }
});
```

but now im confused on how to manage each session individually when their are so many global variables I have that are needed for each session, and would users be able to use the app simultaneously?

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When using express-session you can use the `req.session` object and store your preferred data. In your concrete example you could set all the information about the user you need later in your code to `req.session.user`.
Tiny example:

```
//successful login
req.session.user = {
  userName,
  firstName
}
```

If you need to access any information about the user later, just use `req.session.user.userName` for instance.

This data is stored server-side and is also available in new requests.

**Please also note that the secret shouldn't be the default, instead use a strong & generated password nobody knows.**

Comment: this worked, however, I logged in on safari as my main account, and then went to chrome and tried to render the index page, and it redirected to login (which is good), however, once I logged in with my 2nd main account on chrome, and refreshed on safari, it logged me out of 1st account and logged me into 2nd. how would I manage multiple sessions at the same time?

Comment: Do you have any kind of logic implemented that invalidates/resets a user's session? Did you close Safari before you headed over to Chrome to login there?

Comment: I have it where if the user isn’t logged in, it redirects to the login page and sets `userauth` = false, and then once they login it sets the req.session.user.UserAuth = true. But if i goes to another browser and login, it overrides the last one

Comment: Can you share your full source code? Makes it easier to follow and detect any issues. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited to show the main index function as well as the login functionality. please let me know if you would want to see more code! thanks :)

Comment: I can't really follow your code. I don't know at which point you restrict access for the logged-in user. I noticed a few things though: First, changing `userAuth` variable won't have any effect on `req.session.user.userAuth` and is therefore useless. Second, I would omit the variable `userAuth` completely and just check for `if(req.session.user)` instead. If the user logs out, just set `req.session.user = null`. Also, what effect does `req.body.sessionID` have?

Comment: I also noticed you are using "true" or "false", just use native Booleans instead of Strings as this is considered bad code style.

Comment: I would restrict access for login at the top of the /index function. It says if (userAuth ==“true”) { perform code } else { res.render login.EJs } where the login gets set back to false.  Would it be easier to share the GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes, please share the github repo.

Comment: I actually figured it out, I was not storing user based db2 conn string that I am pulling from my master db2 table in the session, I was storing it globally which caused the db2 conn string to be overridden by the last person to login... but thanks for the help!